# ionic ios build failed with code 65 cordova-plugin-firebase-lib

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:

/Users/andreibobocea/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/2MIL-fmvwsooudyjevcgvbdlehkoxtgwh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/2MIL.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/2MIL.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebasePlugin.o
/Users/andreibobocea/Downloads/handyman-2mil/platforms/ios/2MIL/Plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib/FirebasePlugin.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65

ionic Info:-

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
Cordova Platforms  : ios 5.1.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.11.3
Node       : v8.9.3
npm        : 5.5.1
OS         : macOS
Xcode      : Xcode 12.1 Build version 12A7403
```

cordova-plugin-firebase-lib with 4.1.0 version working fine with my project but it contains some 'UIWebview' component that rejected by Apple as per new policy and when I tried to use latest version 5.1.0 it generate above error.
How to resolve above error

Answer (score 0):

[UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) is the older webview for iOS, newer apps have to use its replacement [WkWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview). Apps using the older webview [will not be accepted](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=edwud51q) by the App Store for much longer. The plugin probably still references the older webview in its code, which is why you're receiving the error.

The plugin itself has now been archived meaning it will not receive any future updates that might resolve this error. See [here](https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib) and [here](https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-plugin-firebase-lib/issues/45).

Fortunately, this plugin was a fork. [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) is another fork that does not seem to have this same issue. Both being forks of the same original plugin, it should be fairly easy to replace the code. Plus, the developers of cordova-plugin-firebase-lib also recommend migrating to this fork.

Comment: I tried to used cordova-plugin-firebasex plugin in project but now my App getting crash with below error after adding  to Reverse Client ID in URL Scheme                      
[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8002ebb0
2020-12-22 14:41:23.809805+0530 2MIL[63531:1837469] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff8002ebb0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x000000010a2e5c68 __64-[FIRPhoneAuthProvider verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion:]_block_invoke + 280
)

Comment: Could you elaborate on what "after adding to Reverse Client ID in URL Scheme" means ? We will need to understand what work was done, to know what caused the exception.

Comment: we get Reverse Client ID from GoogleService-info.plist file like "com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXX" which needs to add in URL Scheme under project.plist file with    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.XXXXXX</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>